# way to add target delay on TimeseriesGenerator from keras.preprocessing.sequence

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, rnn

from deep learning with python book, it created function for data generator.

I thought I can do the same using TimeseiresGenerator from keras package but I was not able to add target delay. Is there any way to do it?

EDIT: I found a way by using np.roll on target data. But if there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: Bounty hunters: Link to the function that was written in the "Deep Learning for Python" book (Written by Francois Chollet, creator of Keras), can be found [here](https://livebook.manning.com/book/deep-learning-with-python/chapter-6/229). I think it is strange that Chollet wrote a function *with* delay in his book, but this functionality *isn't* available in the default tf.keras API. If we come up with an elegant way, maybe I can submit a PR to the tensorflow GitHub. The np.roll solution OP is describing: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940369/add-time-delay-to-timeseriesgenerator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> pandas shift

By default the TimeseriesGenerator performs a lag of 1 timestep. Then, a workaraound is to create a pandas Series, and use the shift function. 
Let train be your sequence, and let forecast be an int representing the "size" of your lag.

Eg:

```
label_train = pd.Series(train)    
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train, label_train.shift(-forecast+1).values)
```

Obs: Be careful to pad your sequence after performing the lag.

Answer (score 0):

To chime in my own two cents;

One can also very easily shift his/her target column up by a couple of observations to create the same effect as a delay; Say you want to predict some time series, but you want to predict the value that lies "3 time steps in the future" from the last observation you are feeding into your time series. You can simply create a column in your dataframe:

```
FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT = 3
df['future'] = df['current'].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
```

Of course, this method will generate 3 `nan` at the end of your dataset which will have to be dealed with somehow. I think a delay parameter in the tf.keras API would be more elegant than this "workaround"